# "Failed To Create Empty Document" error in MDI application in MFC

Tags: mfc, cricheditctrl

I am using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate. I created a new MDI Application, with Tabbed Documents, Document/View Architecture Enabled, Project Style MFC Standard and all other default options in the MFC Application Wizard. The View of my Application derives from CFormView. I add a CRichEditCtrl in the View using the Resource Editor. When, I run this application, I get an error showing a message box "Failed To Create Empty Document". However, everything runs fine for all other controls. Please Help!!

Comment: Problem solved!! By AfxInitRichEdit2 function in Applications InitInstance()

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you initialize rich edit libraries.

Insert AfxInitRichEdit or AfxInitRichEdit2 (if using Rich edit control ver. 2.0) call.
Both are loading appropriate version of the for you RICHED20.DLL (ver2.0) or RICHED32.DLL.

The best place to place this call is App's InitInstance.

Answer (score 1):

add the this code in .h file:
`DECLARE_DYNCREATE(YourClassName)`

and add this code in .cpp file:
`IMPLEMENT_DYNCREATE(YourClassName)`
to replace `DECLARE_DYNAMIC` and `IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC` if they were there.